# best way to syncronize 2 databases

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization, crm

I have 1 database sql on the Microsoft CRM and 1 remote local database sql. They have different schemas.
I must maintain both syncronized (2-way sync). 
They can't communicate directly. So in the middle there is a rest service and a temporary database. 
So, everytime there is an insert or an update on one of the database, the insert or the update is propagated to temporary database and from temporary database to the destination db.
I don't know how to manage conflicts. For example, in both db I have the table PERSON. In a database I update the name, in the other I update the birthday. How can I sync both db without lose both updates?

Thank you

Comment: Is it not possible to make one of them as master and direct all updates to that master database and propagate the updates to the slave later?

Comment: There is no simple switch or program that will do this for you. You basically need to write this software, it's going to be a lot of hard work. What is it that you're asking for really? Where the "set up synchronization" button is? Sorry, there isn't one for this scenario.

Comment: Store the update-history and sync it one at a time order by modified time. Trigger sync when someone update and merge the conflicts. That's a lot of work.

Comment: @Vikdor no, It is not possible because database belong to 2 different system of the same society but different departments.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, yes I have to write the software in fact. There is no setup synchronization. Everytime 1 DML is done the synchronization must start, at least toward to the temporary database.

Comment: @Hendry, you mean to store just modification, not the entire row?

Comment: @Ciccio yeah storing just the modification will do. You can store it in JSON format for data efficiency and performance.